# Why can't I delete using a getContentResolver..?

Tags: android

I can get the data with NO problem...but I cannot delete the data. Any Suggestions..??

```
                Cursor cu = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cu.moveToFirst())
            {
                numberInDb = cu.getString(2);
                System.out.println("Number in DB = " + numberInDb);
            }

            ContentResolver c = getContentResolver();
```

> NEITHER OF THESE NEXT 2 LINES WORK

```
            c.delete(CONTENT_URI, "TITLE ="+ numberInDb, null);
            getContentResolver().delete(CONTENT_URI, "TITLE ="+ numberInDb, null);
```

Comment: You need to go through the questions you have asked and mark the correct answer by checking the checkbox next to the answer that was the most helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this Mayra....but I am checking them now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If TITLE is a string, I suspect that you need to quote it in your query:

```
getContentResolver().delete(CONTENT_URI, "TITLE ='" + numberInDb + "'", null)
```

Also, check the logcat output and see if there are any SQLite errors.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into mine and tried it. It doesn't work either. I get no errors.

Comment: I even hard coded a value in the DB and in the code and it was not removed.

Comment: how can i use path to delete the entry ??i tried MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"DATA '" +..... but the app crashed